# HTML video tag not allowing mp4 playback unless controls are enabled

Tags: html, video, mp4, playback

I have an mp4 on a local machine that I am trying to get to play in a local webpage using the  tag. If the video tag has the 'controls' boolean set to true, the video plays fine. If this boolean is not set, the video won't even attempt to load or auto play (autoplay boolean was tried with no success unless control boolean was set as well). Any help or insight to this annoying behavior is appreciated. (replace autoplay boolean with control boolean in the code below and all of a sudden it works)

```
<video width="480" height="320" autoplay> 
<source src="Triangle.mp4" type="video/mp4">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.